# undefined local variable or method `user' for #<UsersController:0x0000000570eef0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to create a form in two parts. First, you fill in the user form. Then you choose to become a prestataire or a employeur. And by clicking on the respective button, the user form will be saved, and you will be redirected either to the prestataire's form or the employeur's with the recently created user params.

Until now, I didn't manage to send the recently created user params, only saving and redirecting. But then I get this error in the prestataire_controller, since prestataire belong to user. The error is similar when I click on the employeur button:

`undefined local variable or method 'user' for #<UsersController:0x0000000570eef0>`

```
format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
else 
format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" } #This is sublined
format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
end
```

Here is the code I've written so far:

User Form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :civility, 'Titre de civilité: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :civility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :forename, 'Prénom: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :forename %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Nom de famille: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirmation de mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone, 'Numéro de téléphone: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Employeur', name: 'employeur' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Prestataire', name: 'prestataire' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

User controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if params[:commit] == 'employeur'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path, notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path, notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if params[:commit] == 'employeur'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path, notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
private
  def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone, :employeur)
  end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prestataire
  has_one :employeur
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, :forename, :surname, :phone, :civility, presence: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Routes file:

```
Workplace::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :prestataires
    resources :employeurs
  end 
  resources :projets do
    resources :feedbacks
    resources :offres
  end
  root 'projets#index'
```

I was thinking about adding an onclik option on the f.submit and adding an adequate method. But I read somewhere that f.submit was not the best option for this kind of request, but no other suggestion was made. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I guess it should be `@user` here in this line `format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }`

Comment: or simply `new_user_prestataire_path(@user)`? Not sure. And this: `format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }` seems weird.

Comment: Is that line edited in your actual code? I don't see the line similar to the line pointed as error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pavan. This was in fact what was missing! I'm having one last issue though with: if params[:commit] == 'employeur'. When I click on the employeur button, I'm constantly redirected to prestataire. It's like the comparison wasn't working, and it's the else part that is working.

Comment: It is better to ask an another question describing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said,the error is because it should be @user in this line of your `create` action

```
format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
```

And also,you haven't initialized `@user` in your update action which may rise in another error in future.Add this line at the beginning of your update action

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your @user object on update. Try:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if params[:commit] == 'employeur'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path, notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```